# Restricting IDM user to login only from particular machine

Tags: linux, rhel

Have got a requirement to limit a Redhat IDM user to access the client servers only from certain hostname. Aware can do such restriction based on IP but not sure how it can be achieved for particular user. Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: Access how? Using their web browsers, telnetting, logging in via SSH, or by some other means?

Comment: @they logging in via SSH